# Make string a valid file name that can later be viewed as original string

Tags: python

Say I have a string

```
"this is | test"
```

and I want to use that string as a file name but it is not valid to have the `|` character inside a file name. What is the best way to replace all characters that are not valid as a file name with characters that are valid but later on I can read the saved file name by replacing back all the prior replaced invalid characters?

To explain better say the initial string was

```
this is | test
```

then I replaced the string to `"this is # test"` and saved the file now I can re-read that file name as the original string by just replacing the `#` with `|`. What is the best way to achieve this for all invalid strings?

Comment: Does it have to _look like_ the original file name? If not, you can simply `base64` encode the filename. Note that in this case `this is | test` becomes `dGhpcyBpcyB8IHRlc3QK` (but it's fully reversible).

Comment: Yes, that's what you'll get when you decode the encoded string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use URL quoting as URL-safe characters are generally safe for filenames too:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote("this is | test", safe=" ")
'this is %7C test'
>>> urllib.parse.unquote("this is %7C test")
'this is | test'
```

or you can `base64` encode/decode your string:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode("this is | test".encode())
b'dGhpcyBpcyB8IHRlc3Q='
>>> base64.b64decode(b'dGhpcyBpcyB8IHRlc3Q=').decode()
'this is | test'
```